# how to split a huge output using delimiters in perl

Tags: perl

I have a below given output and I want to split it using delimiters using perl.

Example:

```
@output = "00:10:94:00:00:08
           line1
           line2
           line3
           line4
           7.1.1.18    00:10:94:00:00:08
          00:10:94:00:00:09
           line1
           line2
           line3
           line4
           7.1.1.19    00:10:94:00:00:09" ;
```

Now in the above example I have to split the output in such a way I want `00:10:94:00:00:08` and its corresponding lines till it ends with ip `7.1.1.18` and same mac `00:10:94:00:00:08` inside a single index in a array.  Similar another mac and its lines has to be in a another index in a array. After this I have to see whether the supplied mac or an ip matched the output stored in the index.

Comment: Why do you not use blank line as block separator, and read that output block by block?

Comment: Actually there is no blank line in the output I might have mistakenly addded it.  It will be like this.

Comment: @output = "00:10:94:00:00:08
           line1
           line2
           line3
           line4
           7.1.1.18    00:10:94:00:00:08
          00:10:94:00:00:09
           line1
           line2
           line3
           line4
           7.1.1.19    00:10:94:00:00:09 ";

Comment: Then please fix your question first.

Comment: Question fixed,  Can you help now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use global pattern matching to split that sample input to blocks, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "00:10:94:00:00:08
line1
line2
line3
line4
7.1.1.18    00:10:94:00:00:08
00:10:94:00:00:09
line1
line2
line3
line4
7.1.1.19    00:10:94:00:00:09";

while ($str =~ m/([\d:]+)(.*)\1/sg) {
    print ">>>$1 $2 $1<<<\n";
}
```

After that, you could use `split / /` to split them to single lines or fields.

Comment: hi lee I am again back to square 1.  I am currently forced to split them in blocks and store each block inside a single index and then do split line by line and process same.

Comment: Please help on same asap.